# Views Escaping Special Characters in URL

Tags: views

I am creating a view with a list of titles that link to the relevant full article that is also displayed via a view.

The view that contains the article has a contextual filter which contains the Title and the of the views is "mysite.com/%"

So the article that is named "hello world" will be found at "mysite.com/hello-world"

However if the article has the ' special character in it for example "Children's Book" the link that I create to point at the article will be "mysite.com/Children%26#039;s-Books" which brings back an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module you can strip the special Chars. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

Comment: Thanks but I'm sill confused, I am talking about arguments in views rather than the actual alias of the node...unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure under Contextual Filter > More  setting. There are some transform settings.

[image]

Comment: @gilzeroI don't find any option related remove special characters in setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the template for your view, and there escape the string that is sent with urlencode(); assuming that you have the necessary Drupal experience to do that.